# Most efficient way to search large multi nested JSON dataset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What is the most efficient way to search a large dataset of JSON (Up to 27k entries) using jQuery or JS. I'd like to create a search field that runs the function on keyup.

So if a users starts typing it returns all values that match the **title**, along with the link for that title.

My JSON is nested alphabetically A-Z. Example below

```
"Numbers": [
  {
   "Title": "20th Century Period Pieces",
   "Link": "#"
  },
  {
   "Title": "20th Century",
   "Link": "#"
  }
 ],
 "A": [
  {
   "Title": "Action Comedies",
   "Link": "#"
  },
  {
   "Title": "Action",
   "Link": "#"
  }
],
 "B": [
  {
   "Title": "British",
   "Link": "#"
  },
  {
   "Title": "Borderline",
   "Link": "#"
  }
],
// And so forth
```

I'm aware this may cause the browser to freeze up searching such a large list on every keyup so I might have to revert to a search button and loading animation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably not something that can be answered simply. A hashmap, trie or some other non-flat data structure might help. You can take a look at this for something like this approach: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Tree-Structure which would allow you to search more efficient, tho I do not think this is what you want to do. You could also have a backend handle the search and give the results, this is what I would do. So have PHP process the search query and return a new JSON set. Your last option is to just let the browser freeze.
I would prefer the PHP-solution. The loading animation can just wait until PHP returned the data and then show it. This uses the server to process the request, so nothing will freeze - it's a really good solution in my opinion.
For the user, I'd suggest the following: Register keystrokes and give it a "timeout". As soon as the user didn't type for 500ms, query the PHP-script. You can do this via XMLHttpRequest and parse the result using JSON.parse. No need for jQuery here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you should send all that data to the client anyway, if you create an API for the data and filter it via an AJAX request, which returns the filtered result. Looking at your example data, it seems that this isn't user specific, so pulling the data from the database / wherever and caching it seems to be the best solution.

jQueryUI Autocomplete has an example on how to achieve this [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

This is their example, making an AJAX request whenever the user has typed in a minimum of 3 characters:

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
```

You don't have to use jQuery Autocomplete, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map with a structure that is easier to search

```
var map = [];

(function _search(o) {
    if ( typeof o !== 'object' ) return;
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        o.forEach(function(item) { _search(item) });
    } else if ('Title' in o) {
        map.push(o);
    } else {
        for (var key in o) {
            if ( typeof o[key] === 'object' ) {
                if ( Array.isArray(o[key]) ) {
                    o[key].forEach(function(item) { _search(item) });
                } else {
                    _search(o[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}(obj));
```

Then you can just filter the map

```
var result = map.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(SearchValue.toLowerCase()) === 0;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/86tjhn0r/)

Comment: This works a treat! So much quicker and barely any noticeable browser lag. Thank you.